# Display WordPress Shortcode as Plain Text

Tags: wordpress, text, shortcode

Is there any way to display WordPress shortcode as a plain text on the post?
For example to show `[gallery]` just as this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to double the brackets, but you could also replace the brackets as following:

`[ with &#91;`

`] with &#93;`

Comment: You can also use double brackets like `[[gallery]]`.